# Deployment to external server using Circle Ci

Tags: javascript, reactjs, continuous-integration, circleci

It's my first time I'm trying to do that.

I'd like to set up config file in circle.ci in order to deploy my React app to expternal server. Before I just used Ftp connection to upload files to the production server. But now I'd like to do that authomatically. So in my circle config file I've already configured steps to run yarn install and yarn build, all is just doing fine, but the last step needs to be done, I basically have no knowledge how to connect it all, ie. files comes from github, then they are used for build purpose by circle.ci, then I'd like to deploy it to the production server. What is the flow here, and what should I use (ssh somehow, but how?). Thanks

Comment: Read the CircleCI docs on deployment https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/

Comment: Do you mean part about ssh?

Comment: It depends on how you are deploying - are you using docker, or just transferring files to an S3 bucket?

Comment: What is your question exactly? I linked to this document because you seemed to be asking for general guidance on how to implement CD with CircleCI, and that is the official documentation on the topic.

Comment: I just would like to deploy it to the server which is no service like heroku or aws. I just bought webhosting server and would like to deploy built files there. Before I simply used FTP connection to upload files on the server space.

Comment: Btw, I don't use docker's containers in my project

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting provider supports it, I would suggest using rsync over FTP since it will ensure files are replicated without needing to upload everything, only changes.  The --delete option will al\so remove extraneous files on the webhost that you may have removed from github.

```
  - run:
      name: Deploy public folder to YOURDOMAIN
      command: |
        rsync -avz --delete /local/path/ USERNAME@HOSTNAME:/Path/on/remote/server/
```

if yo have not made any changes to default CIrcleCI images, your local path is likely `/home/circleci/project/`